# where is COLLAPSED_CHILD label being added for Collapsed row in HIERARCHICAL TABLE(NATTABLE)

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I'm working on HierarchicalTreeLayerExample from nattable. When I collapse a row, and try to copy a collapsed cell the value previously in that place gets copied. To prevent it from being copied I'm checking the config label of that particular cell is COLLAPSED_CHILD or not. Even though it is a collapsed child it is not showing COLLAPSED_CHILD in the config label stack.

I needed to know where COLLAPSED_CHILD label is being added into the config label stack and also the label accumulator class for COLLAPSED_CHILD label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no label accumulator class that adds the COLLAPSED_CHILD label. It is directly added by the `HierarchicalTreeLayer`.

As the copy operation is done on the `SelectionLayer` and the `HierarchicalTreeLayer` is on top of it, you need to mechanism that connects the two layers.

NatTable provides this via the `HierarchicalTreeCopyDataCommandHandler`

For the example you mentioned the following snippet solves the requirement:

```
    bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer().registerCommandHandler(
            new HierarchicalTreeCopyDataCommandHandler(
                    bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer(),
                    bodyLayerStack.getTreeLayer(),
                    natTable.getInternalCellClipboard()));
```